# Excel charts: Labels on X-axis start at the wrong value

Tags: excel

How do I get the chart pictured below to use labels 1000, 6000, 11000, and so on on the X-axis, rather than 1001, 6001, 11001 and so on? This is a general question not specific to this chart. I've experienced this problem with any single chart I created over the last 20 years.

It didn't bother me a lot before, but now that I am working on producing high quality visualizations, it has become an eyesore big enough to bother me. I hope there is a simple workaround.

Excel chart:

[image: figure 1]

Answer (score 1):

Simply select the respective `axis` -> `right-click` -> `Format Axis...`

Then adjust the bounds as required to e.g., `Minimum:` 1,000 and `Maximum:` 6,000, and the `Major` units to 5,000 (step-size). You could also change the `Minor` units but you do not use tick marks anyways. In effect, adjusting these parameters you can adjust the format of the axis to exactly fit you needs.

---

**EDIT:** Further explanation based on the comment

You need to explicitly select the x-axis by clicking on it so that it is highlighted as shown below (not the yellow part of course):

[image: example]

If this does not work, you can also select the x-axis in the following way; assuming you are able to adjust the y-axis as mentioned in your comment. Select the `y-axis` -> `right click` -> `Format Axis...`.

Inside `Format Axis` you need to select `Axis Options` and select `Horizontal (Value) Axis`:

[image: alternative 2]

Comment: Excel allows me to adjust Minimum and Maximum only for the Y-axis, not for the X-axis.